# sIFR does not work with Adobe CS4

Tags: sifr, flash-cs4

I just recently downloaded sIFR and cannot get the fla source file to open in Adobe CS4. Is anybody else experiencing this problem and if so, have you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about sIFR 2, the download from http://novemberborn.net/sifr/2.0.7 should work. Open the `sifr-cs3.fla`.